# how to transfer joomla website data to another server?

Tags: joomla

I had a joomla website which was perfectly working. at present website is not working bcz of termination web hosting account. I have bought new server & want to tranfer my data in new server. what should i do?

Pls help.

Comment: Just copy files and database, then edit configuration.php database connection info and it will work. Or use Akeeba backup and Akeeba kickstarter for automated process.

Comment: I dont have any backup of database. I only have a back up of website template. now what to do?

Comment: If you cannot access the website or database, there's nothing you can do to transfer website content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the joomla documentation:

"*Copying (Transfering) a Joomla! website is a two-part process: you must copy the files and you must copy the database (which is where the content is stored). Copying the files and copying the database are separate operations.*"

The entire procedure is explained here: [**Copying a Joomla website**](http://docs.joomla.org/Copying_a_Joomla_website)